# Understanding of parsing binary protocol(extra bytes between data types)

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, binary, protocols

I need someone's help. I have a binary protocol and I am trying to parse it(byte array). All things are good, but sometimes there are extra bytes between data types. And I have to skip these bytes for correct parsing. Can anyone explain the reason of these extra bytes?

I have byte array like this:

```
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
106
-8
64
```

I parse first 4 bytes(its 3 - integer number ) and then I skip 4 bytes(what is it???) and parse next 8 bytes(its 10000.0 - double number). So I need to skip that 4 bytes for correct parsing, for what reason??

Comment: Without seeing your input or knowing what type of data you are parsing this is close to impossible to answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. *Which* binary protocol? There are many reasons why "unused" bytes may exist in any given protocol. Reserved bytes (for future extensions), checksums (should not be ignored!), Markers indicating that some option is *not* used, ...

Comment: @Ben i have updated my post

Comment: You need to specify it better -- as @JoachimSauer noted, that data could serve many purposes.  Without a protocol specification you'll get nowhere.

Comment: If this is a binary "protocol" produced by writing native data data types, then I expect that the numbers (integers) at the start are being written in "little-endian" form and they are 4 byte or 8 byte quantities.  (The zeros are probably not "extra bytes" between the numbers.  More likely, they are *part of* the numbers!) But without looking at the code that emits these bytes, we are really just guessing.

Comment: You need to ask the developers who sent you the data in the first place what they are for.  There is no want to infer their purpose esp if they are just zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's padding for alignment. My guess is that protocol assumes 8 bytes initial buffer alignment. The first integer consumes first 4 bytes, then it needs to skip additional 4 bytes to allow 8 bytes alignment to your floating point number (8 bytes double I presume).